# Não convergência das estimativas dos parâmetros do modelo Richards no pacote "nls" do r mesmo com bons chutes inicias

Tags: r

Estou estimando parâmetros de modelos de regressão não linear sigmoidais, apenas o modelo Richards retorna o erro:

```
fator de passos 0.000488281 reduzido abaixo de 'minFactor' de 0.000976562
```

encontrei os chutes iniciais pelo método de análise gráfica, a curva ficou muito próxima dos pontos mas não foi o suficiente para o método convergir.

pesquisando alguns problemas parecidos, a solução aparente que encontrei é modificar o minFactor e maxiter para respectivamente 1/10^6 e 100000, mesmo assim o problema torna a repetir.

Banco de dados:

```
x<-c(60,90,120,150)
y<-c(1.14, 4.22, 19.3, 22.3)
dados<-data.frame(DAP=x, MSTP=y)
```

Gráfico com os chutes iniciais:

```
richar<-function(x){22.3/((1+exp(18.7-0.167*x))^(1/2.1))}

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dados)+
  geom_point(aes(x=DAP, y=MSTP))+
  stat_function(fun=richar)
```

estimação:

```
richards<-nls(y~a/((1+exp(b-c*x))^(1/d)),start = list(a=22.3,b=18.7,c=0.165,d=2.1))
summary(richards)
```

Answer (score 4):

Em linhas gerais, ao ajustar um modelo a um conjunto de dados, procuramos ajustar o modelo mais simples possível no maior conjunto de dados disponível. Lembre-se disso ao ler a minha resposta a seguir.

O problema do teu código está no comando `richards<-nls(y~a/((1+exp(b-c*x))^(1/d)),start = list(a=22.3,b=18.7,c=0.165,d=2.1))`, que não informa ao `R` qual é o conjunto de dados no qual a função `nls` deve ajustar a curva.

```r
x<-c(60,90,120,150)
y<-c(1.14, 4.22, 19.3, 22.3)
dados<-data.frame(DAP=x, MSTP=y)

richar<-function(x){22.3/((1+exp(18.7-0.167*x))^(1/2.1))}

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dados)+
    geom_point(aes(x=DAP, y=MSTP))+
    stat_function(fun=richar)
```

[image]

```r
richards<-nls(y~a/((1+exp(b-c*x))^(1/d)),
                            start = list(a=22.3,b=18.7,c=0.165,d=2.1), 
                            data = dados)
#> Warning in min(x): no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
#> Warning in max(x): no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
#> Error in nls(y ~ a/((1 + exp(b - c * x))^(1/d)), start = list(a = 22.3, : step factor 0.000488281 reduced below 'minFactor' of 0.000976562
summary(richards)
#> Error in summary(richards): object 'richards' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Veja que agora recebi outra mensagem de erro. Por definição, um modelo de regressão não-linear com *m* parâmetros pode ser ajustado a um conjunto com *n* observações, desde que *m* ≤ *n*. No teu caso, *m* = 4 = *n*. Isso pode acarretar vários problemas, como por exemplo, instabilidades numéricas. Veja como a solução para o teu problema é encontrado utilizando um conjunto de dados simulados com apenas três pontos a mais do que no problema original.

```r
x <- seq(60, 150, length.out = 7)
y <- richar(x) + rnorm(7, sd = 1)
dados2<-data.frame(DAP=x, MSTP=y)

ggplot(dados2)+
    geom_point(aes(x=DAP, y=MSTP))+
    stat_function(fun=richar)
```

[image]

```r
richards<-nls(y~a/((1+exp(b-c*DAP))^(1/d)),
                            start = list(a=22.3,b=18.7,c=0.165,d=2.1), 
                            data = dados2)
summary(richards)
#> 
#> Formula: y ~ a/((1 + exp(b - c * DAP))^(1/d))
#> 
#> Parameters:
#>   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> a  20.9785     0.7074  29.655 8.42e-05 ***
#> b  28.3889    16.9568   1.674    0.193    
#> c   0.2451     0.1407   1.742    0.180    
#> d   4.0256     2.9087   1.384    0.260    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.9551 on 3 degrees of freedom
#> 
#> Number of iterations to convergence: 6 
#> Achieved convergence tolerance: 9.361e-06
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Acho muito difícil que o teu problema tenha alguma solução numérica com um modelo tão complexo (4 parâmetros) e tão poucos pontos (4 observações). A partir daqui, há pelo menos duas abordagens possíveis:

1. Utilizar uma função mais simples, como a [função logística](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_log%C3%ADstica), que possui apenas dois parâmetros para serem ajustados. O problema dessa abordagem, acredito eu, é que a função de Richards está sendo utilizada porque, no problema original, cada um dos seus quatro parâmetros deve ter um significado apropriado para o problema real que está sendo considerado aqui.
2. Utilizar mais dados. O problema dessa abordagem é justamente obter estes dados. Isto custa tempo e dinheiro e, em alguns casos, sequer é possível obter dados do mesmo experimento, seja porque não há dinheiro ou porque os corpos utilizados nos ensaios foram destruídos.

Comment: Voto para cima mas em *desde que m ≥ n*  é ao contrário, não é? O número de observações deve ser maior *desde que n ≥ m*.

Comment: Perfeitamente. Acho que eu ainda estava com sono quando escrevi a resposta e me confundi nesse argumento. Obrigado pela correção.